# Gradel Sync Failed Unexpectedly

Tags: android, gradle

> I was using the studio and i imported firebase auth dependencies and my gradle sync failed

Log cat

```
  `Caused by: org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:`
```

Event Log

```
1:00 AM Gradle sync failed: Cause: startup failed:
            build file 'C:\Users\Abhi\Desktop\DESKTOP\MY BOOK\BscIt\build.gradle': 1: unexpected token: < @ line 1, column 1.
            <component name="libraryTable">
            ^
            1 error
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at your `build.gradle` file. The error message indicates that something is wrong there. Most likely the text `<component name="libraryTable">` should not be in there.